# How to apply mist pass on grease pencil objects?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, grease-pencil, render-layers, render-passes

I'm working with a set of grease pencil objects and would like to fade the distant objects using the mist pass but they don't seem to be affected by the pass. What can I convert these strokes into so as to be affected by mist? Thank you!